# location queries in $or in mongo

Tags: mongodb

mongodb does not allow special queries in $or, but i need to run a query that allows me to find documents

```
$or: {{$near: location}, {friend: true}}
```

is there a way to achieve this?

one way i am thinking would be to use:

```
$where: {this.location < some location || friend}
```

but then i'd have to implement the functionality of $near myself and the results would also not be sorted with distance. if there another method to do this?

Comment: this is the error that mongo reports when i run that query

Error: Error: Error: $or may not contain 'special' query

upon looking at the source it turns out that a term in $or cannot have an object. so anything that goes inside {} wont work if it is places under $or.

Comment: Correct Answers is: Mongod DB is shitty design, ticket with this issue is 2 years old. You can do this in: Mysql $or Memsql $or Casandra $or sqlite but Not in Mongodb

Comment: Nope: array('$or' => array(.. $within ..), other condition. Ignore $within and showing all record

Comment: @Userpassword what mongodb version are you using?

Comment: db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5 ---  http://www.images.net.pl/?di=I31T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `$where` is going to be a full table scan you don't want to do that.

You can always do two separate lookups and do the merging on the client side.

Comment: Question is why people choos Mongodb hmm because is fast ?. Solution like merging tables + additional sorting multidimensional array by eq date is miss the point and people should rethinking about choosing Mongodb

Comment: I would say you have to know the capabilities and limits. There's no silver bullet.

Comment: it's a limitation, if you hate it, do not use it. it's perfect for other tasks. now, please stop ranting.

Comment: Other problem $with merging separate lookups - try pagination + sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb support now Goe $or $and query

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3984